# Data is not saved in database but primary key is created Django Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Currently actual data is not save in database but when ever register button is clicked after I input data, an empty data will be saved and primary key will be created. There is no error being posted anywhere but an empty data is saved. I'm using Django Framework for backend and as front-end, I mainly use Javascript and HTML. For database, I use Sqlite. I think the most important part in the data transport is in the Ajax part but since I just used Ajax and Javascript for the first time, I still don't know a lot of thing. Please help me.

script.js

```
function initializePage() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        height: 550,
        lang: "ja",
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        navLinks: true,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        eventSources:[{
            url: '/fullcalendar/calendar',
            method: 'GET',
            failure: function(){
                alert("PROBLEM!!!");
            },
        }
        ],
        select: function(start, end, resource) {
            // 日付選択された際のイベント

                // ダイアログタイトル設定
                $("#dialogTitle").text("スケジュール登録");
                // タイトル初期化
                $("#inputTitle").val("");
                // 備考初期化
                $("#inputDescription").val("");
                // ボタン制御
                $("#registButton").show();
                $("#updateButton").hide();
                $("#deleteButton").hide();
    
                // ダイアログ表示
                $('#inputScheduleForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#inputTitle').focus();
                    }, 500);
                }).modal("show");
    
                // 日付ピッカーの設定
                $('#inputYmdFrom').datetimepicker({locale: 'ja', format : 'YYYY年MM月DD日', useCurrent: false });
                $('#inputYmdTo').datetimepicker({locale: 'ja', format : 'YYYY年MM月DD日', useCurrent: false });
                $('.ymdHm').datetimepicker({
                    locale: 'ja',
                    format : 'YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分'
                });
    
                // 開始終了が逆転しないように制御
                $("#inputYmdFrom").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                    $('#inputYmdTo').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
                });
                $("#inputYmdTo").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                    $('#inputYmdFrom').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
                });
    
                if (this.name == "month") {
                    $('.ymdHm').hide()
                    $('.ymd').show()
    
                    // 終日チェックボックス
                    $('#allDayCheck').prop("checked", true);
                    // 選択された日付をフォームにセット
                    // FullCalendar の仕様で、終了が翌日の00:00になるため小細工
                    var startYmd = moment(start);
                    var endYmd = moment(end);
                    if (endYmd.diff(startYmd, 'days') > 1) {
                        endYmd = endYmd.add(-1, "days");
                    } else {
                        endYmd = startYmd;
                    }
                    $('#inputYmdFrom').val(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
                    $('#inputYmdFrom').data("DateTimePicker").date(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
                    $('#inputYmdTo').val(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
                    $('#inputYmdTo').data("DateTimePicker").date(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
                } else {
                    $('.ymdHm').show();
                    $('.ymd').hide();
    
                    // 終日チェックボックス
                    $('#allDayCheck').prop("checked", false);
                    var startYmd = moment(start);
                    var endYmd = moment(end);
                    $('#inputYmdHmFrom').val(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
                    $('#inputYmdHmFrom').data("DateTimePicker").date(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
                    $('#inputYmdHmTo').val(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
                    $('#inputYmdHmTo').data("DateTimePicker").date(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
                }
    
            },
        eventClick: function(event) {

        // 予定クリック時のイベント
            $("#dialogTitle").text("スケジュール詳細");

            // スケジュールID設定
            $("#scheduleId").val(event.id);
            // タイトル設定
            $("#inputTitle").val(event.title);

            // ボタン制御
            $("#registButton").hide();
            $("#updateButton").show();
            $("#deleteButton").show();

            // ダイアログ表示
            $('#inputScheduleForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#inputTitle').focus();
                }, 500);
            }).modal("show");

            // 日付ピッカーの設定
            $('#inputYmdFrom').datetimepicker({locale: 'ja', format : 'YYYY年MM月DD日', useCurrent: false });
            $('#inputYmdTo').datetimepicker({locale: 'ja', format : 'YYYY年MM月DD日', useCurrent: false });
            $('.ymdHm').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'ja',
                format : 'YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分'
            });

            // 開始終了が逆転しないように制御
            $("#inputYmdFrom").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#inputYmdTo').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            });
            $("#inputYmdTo").on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $('#inputYmdFrom').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
            });

            // 終日チェックボックス
            $('#allDayCheck').prop("checked", true);

            // 選択された日付をフォームにセット
            if (this.name == "month") {
                $('.ymdHm').hide()
                $('.ymd').show()

                // 終日チェックボックス
                $('#allDayCheck').prop("checked", true);
                // 選択された日付をフォームにセット
                // FullCalendar の仕様で、終了が翌日の00:00になるため小細工
                var startYmd = moment(start);
                var endYmd = moment(end);
                if (endYmd.diff(startYmd, 'days') > 1) {
                    endYmd = endYmd.add(-1, "days");
                } else {
                    endYmd = startYmd;
                }
                $('#inputYmdFrom').val(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
                $('#inputYmdFrom').data("DateTimePicker").date(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
                $('#inputYmdTo').val(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
                $('#inputYmdTo').data("DateTimePicker").date(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
            } else {
                $('.ymdHm').show();
                $('.ymd').hide();

                // 終日チェックボックス
                $('#allDayCheck').prop("checked", false);
                var startYmd = moment(event.start);
                var endYmd = moment(event.end);
                $('#inputYmdHmFrom').val(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
                $('#inputYmdHmFrom').data("DateTimePicker").date(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
                $('#inputYmdHmTo').val(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
                $('#inputYmdHmTo').data("DateTimePicker").date(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
            }
        },
    });
}

function registSchedule() {

    // 開始終了日付の調整
    var startYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdFrom').val() + "00時00分00", 1));
    var endYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdTo').val() + "00時00分00", 1));
    var allDayCheck = $('#allDayCheck').prop("checked");
    if (!allDayCheck) {
        startYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdHmFrom').val() + "00", 1));
        endYmd = moment(formatNengappi($('#inputYmdHmTo').val() + "00", 1));
    }
    if (endYmd.diff(startYmd, 'days') > 0) {
        endYmd = endYmd.add(+1, "days");
    }

    // 非同期でサーバーにリクエストを送信
    var EventData = {
            id: $("#scheduleId").val(),
            title: $('#inputTitle').val(),
                // title: event.title,
            start: startYmd.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"),
            end: endYmd.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"),
            allDay: allDayCheck,
        };
        alert("3!");
    sendAjaxRequest("add_event", EventData);
        }

function sendAjaxRequest(method, EventData) {

    var cal = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView");
    EventData.searchStart = cal.start;
    EventData.searchEnd = cal.end;

    // 処理名を設定
    var methodName = "登録";
    if (method == "update") {
        methodName = "更新"
    } else if (method == "remove") {
        methodName = "削除"
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/fullcalendar/" + method,
        type: "GET",
        //JSON data -> string
        // data: JSON.stringify(EventData),
        // data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            // カレンダー再描画
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            $('#inputScheduleForm').modal('hide');
            alert("予定を" + methodName + "しました。");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("予定の" + methodName + "に失敗しました。");
        }
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}

function allDayCheckClick(element) {
    if (element && element.checked) {

        // 日付に変換して設定
        var startYmdHm = formatNengappi($("#inputYmdHmFrom").val() + "00", 1);
        var endYmdHm = formatNengappi($("#inputYmdHmTo").val() + "00", 1);
        var startYmd = moment(startYmdHm);
        var endYmd = moment(endYmdHm);
        $("#inputYmdFrom").val(startYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));
        $("#inputYmdTo").val(endYmd.format("YYYY年MM月DD日"));

        // 表示切替
        $('.ymdHm').hide();
        $('.ymd').show();

    } else {
        // 日時に変換して設定
        var startYmd = formatNengappi($("#inputYmdFrom").val(), 0);
        var endYmd = formatNengappi($("#inputYmdTo").val(), 0);
        var startYmdHm = moment(startYmd + "T" + moment().format("HH") + ":00:00");
        var endYmdHm = moment(startYmd + "T" + moment().format("HH") + ":00:00").add(1, "hours");
        $("#inputYmdHmFrom").val(startYmdHm.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));
        $("#inputYmdHmTo").val(endYmdHm.format("YYYY年MM月DD日 HH時mm分"));

        // 表示切替
        $('.ymdHm').show();
        $('.ymd').hide();
    }
}

function formatNengappi(nengappi, flg) {
    var ret = nengappi.replace("年", "-").replace("月", "-").replace("日", "");
    if (flg == 1){
        ret = nengappi.replace("年", "-").replace("月", "-").replace("日", "T").replace("時",":").replace("分",":").replace(" ","");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

views.py

```
def add_event(request):
     title = request.GET.get("title", None)
     start = request.GET.get("start", None)
     end = request.GET.get("end", None)
     event = Events(title=str(title), start=start, end=end)
     event = Events.objects.create(
              title = title,
              start = start,
              end = end,
         )
     event.save()
     data = {}
     return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: I believe you need to specify the `data: ` in your `sendAjaxRequest` `$.ajax` function. [docs](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/fullcalendar/" + method,
        type: "GET",
        data: {'title': EventData.title, 'start': EventData.start, 'end': EventData.end},
        success: function() {
            // カレンダー再描画
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            $('#inputScheduleForm').modal('hide');
            alert("予定を" + methodName + "しました。");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("予定の" + methodName + "に失敗しました。");
        }
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```